# Click go to modal section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

this is what I want to achieve:

[image]

The modal has 4 sections, each section loads it´s content dinamically using .load() to the container on the right.

The problem is that I have a menu in the footer that opens the modal, and should put the user in the correct section:

[image]

I just don´t know how to make it, for example if I click on the footer menu 'metodos de pago' ***it open the modal in that specified section***. any ideas on how to do it?

this is my script to load the modal:

```
function loadmodal(){
     $('.info_modal').fadeIn();
}
```

this is my script to load the content of the sections in the modal after clicking on the left menu:

```
function loadcontent(){
     $('.info_modal_content').load('includes/text2.html');
}
```

markup of the modal:

```
    <div class="info_modal">
        <div class="info_modal_container">
            <h2>Guia de compra</h2>
            <hr>
            <ul class="info_modal_menu">
                <li>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)">Como Comprar</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="loadcontent()">Metodos de pago</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)">Cambios y devoluciones</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)">Tarjeta regalo</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="info_modal_content">
                <h2>TARGETA PUEDES COMPRARLA EN...</h2>
                <p>Tu tarjeta puede ser rechazada por una de las</p>
            </div>

            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="close_contact" onclick="closecontactmodal()"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You should use `.fadeIn()` instead of `.fadeIn`

Comment: fixed it in the question, but it´s right in my code... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not pass through a URL for the initial load?

Assuming your footer is structured something like:

```
<footer>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="text1.html" class="openModal">Text 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="text2.html" class="openModal">Text 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="text3.html" class="openModal">Text 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="text4.html" class="openModal">Text 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</footer>
```

And then you could attach a handler to `.openModal`:

```
$('.openModal').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  var toLoad = $(this).attr('href');

  $('.info_modal_content').load(toLoad);

  $('.info_modal').fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: thanks ahren, but how to markup the menu inside the modal? :S

Comment: @fxg - You could actually use the exact same code as above, and the same structure in terms of links. `fadeIn()` would be ignored if it's already visible.